# How to use ChartJS Radar Plot in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to use the chartJSRadar() instead of webplot() in the example below. Is it possible? I do not know the function of webplot() but I need to use a radar chart in this place. Use of this function starts with 33 lines. The code can also be found here: https://gist.github.com/mbannert/9124890/

```
data_sets <- c("mtcars")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Drop-down selection box for which data set
  output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
    selectInput("dataset", "Data set", as.list(data_sets))
  })

  # select a car
  output$choose_car <- renderUI({
    selectInput("car","car",as.list(rownames(get(input$dataset))))
  })


  # Check boxes
  output$choose_columns <- renderUI({
    # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
    if(is.null(input$dataset))
      return()

    # Get the data set with the appropriate name
    dat <- get(input$dataset)
    colnames <- names(dat)

    # Create the checkboxes and select them all by default
    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns", 
                       choices  = colnames,
                       selected = colnames)
  })


  output$radar <- renderPlot({
    source("radar.R")
    webplot(get(input$dataset),
            which(rownames(mtcars) == input$car), y.cols = input$columns,add=F)
  })

  # Output the data
  output$data_table <- renderTable({
    # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
    if(is.null(input$dataset))
      return()

    # Get the data set
    dat <- get(input$dataset)

    # Make sure columns are correct for data set (when data set changes, the
    # columns will initially be for the previous data set)
    if (is.null(input$columns) || !(input$columns %in% names(dat)))
      return()

    # Keep the selected columns
    dat <- dat[, input$columns, drop = FALSE]

    # Return first 20 rows
    head(dat, 20)
  })
})
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Car Comparison Radar"),

  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("choose_dataset"),
    uiOutput("choose_car"),

    uiOutput("choose_columns"),
    br(),
    a(href = "http://statisticstoproveanything.blogspot.de/2013/11/spider-web-plots-in-r.html",
      "Radar by Alan Vaughn from statisticstoproveanything"),
     br(),
    a(href = "https://gist.github.com/mbannert/9124890/",
      "Find the shiny code gist here.")

  ),


  mainPanel(

    plotOutput(outputId = "radar", height = "600px"),
    tableOutput("data_table")    
  )
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some other warnings that the app is throwing that I didn't touch, but this works:

```
library(shiny)
library(chartjs)

data_sets <- c("mtcars")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Drop-down selection box for which data set
  output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
    selectInput("dataset", "Data set", as.list(data_sets))
  })

  # select a car
  output$choose_car <- renderUI({
    selectInput("car","car",as.list(rownames(get(input$dataset))))
  })


  # Check boxes
  output$choose_columns <- renderUI({
    # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
    if(is.null(input$dataset))
      return()

    # Get the data set with the appropriate name
    dat <- get(input$dataset)
    colnames <- names(dat)

    # Create the checkboxes and select them all by default
    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns", 
                       choices  = colnames,
                       selected = colnames)
  })


  output$radar <- renderChartjs({

    # Get the data set
    dat <- get(input$dataset)

    # Make sure columns are correct for data set (when data set changes, the
    # columns will initially be for the previous data set)
    if (is.null(input$columns) || !(input$columns %in% names(dat)))
      return()

    # Keep the selected columns
    dat <- dat[, input$columns, drop = FALSE]

    #row data for plot
    car <- as.vector(t(dat[row.names(dat) == input$car,]))

    chartjs() %>%
      cjsRadar(labels = colnames(dat)) %>%
      cjsSeries(data = car) %>% 
      cjsEditScale(axis = NULL, ticks = list(beginAtZero = TRUE))

  })

  # Output the data
  output$data_table <- renderTable({
    # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
    if(is.null(input$dataset))
      return()

    # Get the data set
    dat <- get(input$dataset)

    # Make sure columns are correct for data set (when data set changes, the
    # columns will initially be for the previous data set)
    if (is.null(input$columns) || !(input$columns %in% names(dat)))
      return()

    # Keep the selected columns
    dat <- dat[, input$columns, drop = FALSE]

    # Return first 20 rows
    head(dat, 20)
  })
})

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Car Comparison Radar"),

  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("choose_dataset"),
    uiOutput("choose_car"),

    uiOutput("choose_columns"),
    br(),
    a(href = "http://statisticstoproveanything.blogspot.de/2013/11/spider-web-plots-in-r.html",
      "Radar by Alan Vaughn from statisticstoproveanything"),
    br(),
    a(href = "https://gist.github.com/mbannert/9124890/",
      "Find the shiny code gist here.")

  ),


  mainPanel(

    chartjsOutput(outputId = "radar", height = '75px'),
    tableOutput("data_table")    
  )
))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the chartjs package is not up to date, in my work I have to use the radarchart package, can you rewrite it?

Comment: I added a new answer below that uses the radarchart package.  I'd stick with chartjs - even though the documentation hasn't been updated.  It looks much better.  For that reason, I'll leave both of my answers.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you could do it this way if you really want to stick with the radarchart library:

```
library(shiny)
library(radarchart)

data_sets <- c("mtcars")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Drop-down selection box for which data set
  output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
    selectInput("dataset", "Data set", as.list(data_sets))
  })

  # select a car
  output$choose_car <- renderUI({
    selectInput("car","car",as.list(rownames(get(input$dataset))))
  })


  # Check boxes
  output$choose_columns <- renderUI({
    # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
    if(is.null(input$dataset))
      return()

    # Get the data set with the appropriate name
    dat <- get(input$dataset)
    colnames <- names(dat)

    # Create the checkboxes and select them all by default
    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns", 
                       choices  = colnames,
                       selected = colnames)
  })


  output$radar <- renderChartJSRadar({

    # Get the data set
    dat <- get(input$dataset)

    # Make sure columns are correct for data set (when data set changes, the
    # columns will initially be for the previous data set)
    if (is.null(input$columns) || !(input$columns %in% names(dat)))
      return()

    # Keep the selected columns
    dat <- dat[, input$columns, drop = FALSE]

    #reform data for plot
    dat <- as.data.frame(t(dat), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    dat$labs <- row.names(dat)

    dat <- dat[, c('labs', input$car)]

    chartJSRadar(dat)

  })

  # Output the data
  output$data_table <- renderTable({
    # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
    if(is.null(input$dataset))
      return()

    # Get the data set
    dat <- get(input$dataset)

    # Make sure columns are correct for data set (when data set changes, the
    # columns will initially be for the previous data set)
    if (is.null(input$columns) || !(input$columns %in% names(dat)))
      return()

    # Keep the selected columns
    dat <- dat[, input$columns, drop = FALSE]

    # Return first 20 rows
    head(dat, 20)
  })
})

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Car Comparison Radar"),

  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("choose_dataset"),
    uiOutput("choose_car"),

    uiOutput("choose_columns"),
    br(),
    a(href = "http://statisticstoproveanything.blogspot.de/2013/11/spider-web-plots-in-r.html",
      "Radar by Alan Vaughn from statisticstoproveanything"),
    br(),
    a(href = "https://gist.github.com/mbannert/9124890/",
      "Find the shiny code gist here.")

  ),


  mainPanel(
    chartJSRadarOutput('radar', height = '350px'),
    #chartjsOutput(outputId = "radar", height = '75px'),
    tableOutput("data_table")    
  )
))
```